# Some plugins have to be updated if using Phonegap >= 4.0.0. Error on filetransfer.java

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

> Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: FileTransfer.java - You can fix this here

I suddenly have this error when I try to build my app on build.phonegap.com for Android. None of my backups work either, although in iOS everything works okay. I had already tried to add `source="npm"` to all my plugins, but it doesn't work either (it builds but all the CSS gets messed up). The only plugin that I'm using is the Facebook API, all the rest are by default. I seriously need help please, my app is already finished and my client is going crazy because this app should be delivered next week. Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<?XML version='1.0' Encoding='utf-8'?>
<Widget id="com.phonegap.eventsrelease" version="1.0.0" Xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name></name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <author email="hcorazao@gmail.com">

    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
    <!--preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" /-->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>

    <!-- If you're using PhoneGap Build -->
    <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin"/>
    </feature>

    <!-- The Params name are changed for this forum-->
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="xxxxxx" />
    </gap:plugin>

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
    <!--gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/splash_image.jpg" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/splash_image.jpg" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/splash_image.jpg" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/splash_image.jpg" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/splash_image.jpg" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/splash_image.jpg" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/splash_image.jpg" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/splash_image.jpg" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/splash_image.jpg" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/splash_image.jpg" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/splash_image.jpg" /-->
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="320" height="480"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="640" height="960"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/splash_image.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Please always avoid swear words in your posts.

Comment: any one one help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873787/error-some-official-plugins-have-to-be-updated-if-using-phonegap-4-0-0-ple

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Phonegap Build to work at all with over 4.0.0 until I went through the painstaking process of looking up all of the NPM package names and converted them like so:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
```

I'd suggest you try doing the same and seeing if that allows your project to build and work correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

My plugins started working again (I used to have `source="npm"` with no version specified) when I used this syntax:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" spec="0.2.15" source="pgb" />
```

The error went away once I specified a version type.